# Waitint for kill alarm to trigger

Tags: c

I m coding a program in bash using C where I create a child process and I trigger a 5 second alarm to kill that created process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
/*programa que temporiza la ejecución de un proceso hijo */


int pid;

void sig_handler(int signum){
 
    kill(pid, SIGKILL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "No hay suficientes argumentos\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char* exeProgram = argv[1];
    char** arguments;
    if(argc > 2){
        arguments = malloc(10*(argc + 2));
        arguments[0] = exeProgram;
        for(int i = 1; i < argc -1; ++i){
            arguments[i] = argv[i+1];
        }
        arguments[argc+1] = NULL;
    }
    pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0){
        signal(SIGALRM, sig_handler);
        alarm(5);
        int status;
        int returnedPID;
        do{
            returnedPID =waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
        }while(errno != EINTR );
        if ((returnedPID == -1)) perror("wait() error");
        else {
            if (WIFEXITED(status))
                printf("child exited with status of %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
                printf("child was terminated by signal %d\n",WTERMSIG(status));
            else printf("reason unknown for child termination");
        }
        
    }
    else if(pid == 0) {
        execvp(exeProgram, arguments);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that once the alarm is triggered and the wait executed, the wait ends immediately with a successful termination of the child program. I know that there are two ways of solving this, relaunching the wait if the signal received is not a EINTR type or setting the sigaction flags to SA_RESTART, but I don't know how to do the last option and the first one doesn't seem to work. I m currently learning bash and any help is welcome.

Comment: Why is this tagged bash? It's 100% purely C. A C program doesn't care what its parent process is unless you go out of its way to make it do so, so whether you _run it_ from bash or with some other parent process (a GUI, a Python interpreter, a baseline-POSIX shell, etc) makes no difference.

Comment: ...I would also suggest considering use of the prebuilt coreutils `timeout` program instead of rolling your own. Indeed, reviewing [the source code to `timeout`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/timeout.c) might be useful.

Comment: When `argc` is 2 it seems you call `execvp` with an uninitialized `arguments`

Comment: How do you start this program, i.e. command line.